# What Javascript feature is being used here?

Tags: javascript, react-apollo

I'm studying React and Apollo JS and came across this syntax.

What JS feature is being used where **Launches** is declared below?

```
const Launches: React.FC<LaunchesProps> = () => {
  const {
    data,
    loading,
    error
  } = useQuery<
    GetLaunchListTypes.GetLaunchList,
    GetLaunchListTypes.GetLaunchListVariables
  >(GET_LAUNCHES);

  if (loading) return <Loading />;
  if (error) return <p>ERROR</p>;
  if (!data) return <p>Not found</p>;

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Header />
      {data.launches &&
        data.launches.launches &&
        data.launches.launches.map((launch: any) => (
          <LaunchTile key={launch.id} launch={launch} />
        ))}
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: That's Typescript not Javascript, and it's a static type annotation.

Comment: Ahhh gotcha, thank you!  If you want you can answer below so I can mark it as the answer for this thread?

Comment: Done. I tried to explain what it means a bit as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's Typescript not Javascript, and it's a static type annotation.

It types that function as a React Function Component with the type LaunchesProps as the type of the props it receives.